# Google charts legend manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Using google area chart: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart.html

Does anyone know how I can freelly manipulate the legends?

Pretty much I want one of two:

- Be able to freelly set each legend element somewhere.
- Set the legend that is displayed in one line to have multiple lines if the size of the legend exceeds the width of the legend area. (Prefered)

I would avoid hacks to manipulate the svg within the iframe btw.

Comment: I need this as well... any luck?

Comment: unfortunately you can't manipulate the legends inside the SVG :( at most in your case you can disable them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a way to manipulate the legends as we wish.
In the question of the bounty:
You can use

in two of the charts

```
legend : 'none'
```

and also use colours to guarantee that all elements have the same colour.

```
colors:['red','#004411']
```

Other than that we can't manipulate them much more unfortunately :(

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/13639884/661584 pls, the alternative is to create them entirely ourselves with html . jscript / json etc as we like. Full control.

Comment: Actually there are ways to customize the legends, here is one of the many examples: http://codepen.io/panchalkalpesh/pen/bgebwQ

Answer (score 16):

For **full** control I'd suggest **turning them off**

```
legend : { position:"none"}
```

**Creating your own** totally customised legend outside the chart with html.

Then binding your custom legend up to the chart using the select event, combined with click or hover / focus events (whatever you want) on your custom legend.

see https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#interaction_using_events for a start.

Comment: I have just submitted a feature request for this https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1943&thanks=1943&ts=1427969500

Comment: @MartinJoiner not sure that link is correct, looks like and empty github project - am I missing something?

Comment: It seems that since I posted that link, Google Visualization have decided to track change requests and bug reports in GIT Hub. I would provide an updated direct link here but my ticket is buried somewhere in a list of 1,537 tickets at time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this (it's depends on the font that you use, you need fetch the proportion of your font)

```
var my_legend = "this is my legend x";

var len_legend = my_legend.length;

var width_graph = 400;

var chars_per_line = width_graph / [REPLACE_BY_PROPORTION]

if (len_legend > chars_per_line) {

    my_legend = wordwrap(my_legend, 20, '<br/>\n');

}
```

AND THE WRAP WORD FUNCTION (or anything like this)

```
function wordwrap( str, width, brk, cut ) {

    brk = brk || '\n';

    width = width || 75;

    cut = cut || false;

    if (!str) { return str; }

    var regex = '.{1,' +width+ '}(\\s|$)' + (cut ? '|.{' +width+ '}|.+$' : '|\\S+?(\\s|$)');


return str.match( RegExp(regex, 'g') ).join( brk );

}
```

SO FOR your code...

replace values at

```
var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document....
```

etc

by your vars.

not use `width = 400`, use width, and so on... and your string.

Comment: sorry by the quotes, as javascript i cant do the syntax lighter... check this out with my idea: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/wordwrap-for-javascript/

Comment: This doesn't make sense?  How does this relate to the chart?

Comment: yo do it when you -make- the chart. Please paste the code generation of your chart

Comment: Can you show me an example where this is plugged in with 2 charts?

Comment: in the link that you use, there's the javascript code where there are the vars to update like i said

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for any smarter solution than mine so I saw this question.

My current solution is to find html element that contains legend and manipulate with them as you would with your own custom html element. (You will have to deal with SVG elems here, though)

```
document.getElementById('pie-chart').getElementsByTagName('g')[0].setAttribute("style", "transform: translate(-130px)");
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do I see the following solutions.

- "Be able to freelly set each legend element somewhere."

According to the documentation, you only have the position options of "bottom", "left", "in", "none", "right", and "top". If you want to "freely" set the set the location, I think you need to hack the chart using JavaScript after it is rendered.

- "Set the legend that is displayed in one line to have multiple lines if the size of the legend exceeds the width of the legend area. (Prefered)"

I have found that using adding maxlines to the legend enables multiple lines (ex. "maxLines: 5"), but this does not always have each legend category on its own line.

Source: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart?csw=1