# change color of data title (Google Visualization)

Tags: javascript, colors, google-visualization, linechart

I'm trying to change the colors of a  line graph (Google visualization). 
Thats works but I can't find how I need to change the color of the "Cats" text.
[image]

As what is it descriped here? https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['x', 'Cats', 'Blanket 1', 'Blanket 2'],
    ['A',   1,       1,           0.5],
    ['B',   2,       0.5,         1],
    ['C',   4,       1,           0.5],
    ['D',   8,       0.5,         1],
    ['E',   7,       1,           0.5],
    ['F',   7,       0.5,         1],
    ['G',   8,       1,           0.5],
    ['H',   4,       0.5,         1],
    ['I',   2,       1,           0.5],
    ['J',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
    ['K',   3,       1,           0.5],
    ['L',   3.5,     0.5,         1],
    ['M',   1,       1,           0.5],
    ['N',   1,       0.5,         1]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 10}}
          );
}
```

Another question
This is my current work, but why do I see - 5 mil even there is no number below 0 ?

[image]

My code:

```
new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
    draw(data, {
                curveType: "function",
                width: 900, height: 300,
                vAxis: {minValue:0},
                colors: ['#769dbb'], //Line color
                backgroundColor: '#1b1b1b',
                hAxis: { textStyle: {color: '#767676'  , fontSize: 11} },
                vAxis: { textStyle: {color: '#767676'} },
                }
        );
```

}

​

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break up your question into two parts.

**Customizing Your Legend**

For your first question, the [API documentation](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) doesn't really give us direct access to the legend itself.   I think the best way to solve your problem would be to start by turning off the default legend:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'))
.draw(data, {
    legend: { position: "none" }, // turn off the legend
    curveType: "function",
    width: 900, height: 300,
    vAxis: {minValue:0},
    colors: ['#769dbb'], //Line color
    backgroundColor: '#1b1b1b',
    hAxis: { textStyle: {color: '#767676'  , fontSize: 11} },
    vAxis: { textStyle: {color: '#767676'} },
});
```

Once you have completed this, you can create your own legend by interacting with the map itself:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', drawCustomLegend);
```

Check out the [documentation on handling chart events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events), as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13639884/616937).

**Configuring Axis Dimensions**

To remove the -5 million horizontal axis value, you can set your `vAxis.minValue` to 0.  So to put it all together:

```
var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'))
.draw(data, {
    legend: { position: "none" }, // turn off the legend
    curveType: "function",
    width: 900, height: 300,
    vAxis: {minValue:0},
    colors: ['#769dbb'], //Line color
    backgroundColor: '#1b1b1b',
    hAxis: { textStyle: {color: '#767676'  , fontSize: 11} },
    vAxis: { minValue: 0, textStyle: {color: '#767676'} },
});
```

Comment: awesome thanks, Because you said its called legend, I searched and found. `legend.textStyle`

Comment: Yes, the legend.textStyle is what you want if you want a uniform style for all elements in your legend.  You'll need a custom legend for more fine-grained configuration.

Comment: I have added `hAxis: { minValue: 0 }` , but I still see it

Comment: My bad.  Change move your minValue to `vAxis`.  Editing my answer.

Comment: hmmm. The docs do mention that `minValue` will actually be the minimum of "the minValue option value, or the lowest data value, rounded down to the next lower grid mark."  Is your lowest graph value < 0?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22769/discussion-between-kyle-and-sharpless512)

Comment: The vAxis should be able to be set as zero if there are no data values below it. If you change one of the data points to -1, you can use the following options: `                  vAxis: {
                    maxValue: 10,
                    viewWindowMode: 'explicit',
                    viewWindow: {
                      min: 0,
                    }      
                  }` this will set your axis to be a minimum of zero.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Check out the "legend" property below.

```
options='{"title": "Abandoned Carts",
              "backgroundColor" : "transparent",
              "pieHole": "0.4",
              "legend" : { "textStyle" : { "color" : "white"} }
              }'
```