# How can i make custom legend marker for google donut pie chart?

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, legend

I am new to angularjs and google charts, I am using google charts for donut pie charts but I have ended up with no option to change the default legend marker for donut pie charts which is a circle.

So how can I add custom legend marker to pie chart using google charts?

Here is my code (Index.html):

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div google-chart chart="chart"></div>
</body>
```

Script.js:

```
     var app = angular.module('myApp', [ 'googlechart' ]);

      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
         var chart1 = {};
          chart1.type = "PieChart";
          chart1.data = [
          ['Component', 'cost'],
          ['Software', 50000],
          ['Hardware', 80000]
          ];
         chart1.data.push(['Services',20000]);
         chart1.options = {
            displayExactValues: true,
            pieSliceText:'value',
            donut:'true',
            pieHole:.5,
            width: 400,
            height: 200,
           chartArea: {left:10,top:10,bottom:0,height:"100%"}
          };
          $scope.chart = chart1;

});
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks

Comment: You will have to manually make a legend outside of the chart if you want to manipulate the shape.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13639884/661584

Comment: @RobSchmuecker can you give me one implemented example?

Comment: Sorry I can't but it's pretty simple.  Make a separate legend in HTML in whichever way you like with the same colours as your `Pie` colours.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker how can append that in google charts legend ?

Comment: You purposely need to omit your google charts legend and make your own in plain HTML/CSS/Javascript

Comment: @RobSchmuecker that's what i am talking that legend in google charts load on run time then how i capture them and remove them and also add my custom one to there same place?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202029/hiding-the-legend-in-google-chart shows that if you add `legend: {position: 'none'}` in your options your legend will not show up.  You need to define your own colours for your data and then use that same colour to build up your own legend.

Comment: @RobSchmuecker yes you are right but pie charts are rendered inside svg and that is rendered on  runtime then how can i append my html this is the issue

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle.

Comment: here is plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/2CNK6njPJMNHiB26MZZ5?p=preview @RobSchmuecker

Comment: Here you can add colors like this http://plnkr.co/edit/phYdDsD0c4jkvpl2F2JM?p=preview and then do whatever your heart desires to make a HTML legend

Comment: @RobSchmuecker if you have some time please give me one example how do i add custom legend to this pie chart like ' software' and its marker type is square?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible. I have exactly the same problem. The only way - is to turn off the legend - `legend : 'none'`, and make it yourself. Details here:
[Google charts legend manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7804129/google-charts-legend-manipulation)

Comment: its better to use d3 for charts instead of google charts i achieved what i wanted using d3